# How to create predicate dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, predicatebuilder

Hi i want to create a list based on the search string using predicate expressions.

I have a list of type products contains different names.

```
List<products> list1 = new List<products>();

        list1.Add(new products("sowmya"));
        list1.Add(new products("Jane"));
        list1.Add(new products("John"));
        list1.Add(new products("kumar"));
        list1.Add(new products("ramya"));
        listBox1.ItemsSource = list1;
```

Now i want to filter the content based on user input.User will enter n no of strings with '+' as separator. After receiving the strings i will pass them to predicate object like this

```
 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        List<products> list2 = new List<products>();
        Expression<Func<products, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<products>();
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            string Searchstring = textBox1.Text.ToString().Trim();
            string[] separator = new string[] { "+" };
            string[] SearchItems=Searchstring.Split(separator,StringSplitOptions.None);
            foreach (string str in SearchItems)
            {
                string temp = str;
                predicate =p => p.Name.Contains(temp.ToLower());                   
            }

            list2 = list1.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).ToList();
            listBox1.ItemsSource = list2;
        }
    }
```

If i enter more than one string(sowmya+jane+john) its giving only the last string(john) result but i want a list of all matching strings

Please answer this question because i'm trying this but i couldn't get the result.

Please do some help thanks.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845059/how-do-i-dynamically-create-an-expressionfuncmyclass-bool-predicate

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Initialize the predicate as false

```
Expression<Func<products, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<products>();
```

You need to combine the predicates using `Or`

```
foreach (string str in SearchItems)
{
    string temp = str;
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.NameToLower().Contains(temp.ToLower()));                   
}
```

Source for predicate builder [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). It is part of [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

Code, in case link goes

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class PredicateBuilder
{
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> ()  { return f => true;  }
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }
}
```

Comment: If i use And to combine predicates its giving all the list items but not the matching string result

Comment: @Sowmya updated my answer. you need to use `temp` not `str` inside the predicate

Comment: Hey Eranga thank you soooo much its working fine. Really you helped me

Comment: Is this `predicatebuilder` the same to this article http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx?

Comment: `PredicateBuilder`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to build a predicate here. You can try something like this

```
List<products> list1 = new List<products>();

list1.Add(new products("sowmya"));
list1.Add(new products("Jane"));
list1.Add(new products("John"));
list1.Add(new products("kumar"));
list1.Add(new products("ramya"));

string input = "aaa+kuma+ram";
List<string> searchStrings =
    input.Split(new string[] { "+" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => s.ToLower())
    .ToList();

List<products> list2 = (
    from p in list1
    where searchStrings.Any(s => p.Name.Contains(s))
    select p).ToList();
```

list2 will contain "kumar" and "ramya".

Comment: Thank u and this will work and working also i knew that but i need to construct it by using predicate only please help me

Comment: @Sowmya then you should try what Eranga suggests.

Answer (score 1):

As I am not sure that predicate instance has an And method, I suggest you use this code:

```
var list = list1.AsQueryable();
foreach (string str in SearchItems)
{
     list = list.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(str.ToLower()));
}
listBox1.ItemsSource = list.ToList();
```

Comment: if i use this code its giving only one string result but if i enter two strings its not giving any result.Please find the solution.I need it.

Comment: that might be because of the first `.ToLower()` I just added. if not make sure your `Name` property really contains both of the strings you search for

Comment: same issue again giving the last string result only.Ya i'm sure The "Name" property contains both the strings

Comment: you should check if you have copied and pasted the code correctly then.