# Searching by regexp when constructing LINQ expression using Expression classes

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845059/how-do-i-dynamically-create-an-expressionfuncmyclass-bool-predicate) is the post which describes the way to create an `Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>` predicate dynamically. Here is a snippet:

```
 var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "p");
    var len = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "SomeText");
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        len, Expression.Constant("Text"));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(
        body, param);
```

I wonder how do I apply a regexp to a string instead of Equality. Is there a possibility?
A possible pseudo code would be  like:

```
 var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "p");
    var len = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "SomeText");
    var body = Expression.Regexp(
        len, @"\D+");

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(
        body, param);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Expression.Call(Type type, string methodName, Type[] typeArguments, params Expression[] arguments)` to call your test method that checks for regular expression.

```
 List<string> lista = new List<string>() { "aaaa", "aaabb", "aaacccc", "eee" };

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s");
        var pattern = Expression.Constant("\\Aa");

        var test = Expression.Call(typeof(Regex), "IsMatch", null, param, pattern);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(test, param);

        IEnumerable<string> query = lista.Where(lambda.Compile());

        foreach (string s in query) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Comment: Where does this string come from - "IsMatch"?

Comment: Suppose you have the following structure                            var data = new List<TestClass>
                           {
                               new TestClass {Name = "valvoline", Quantity = 3},
                               new TestClass {Name = "castrol", Quantity = 3},
                               new TestClass {Name = "valve", Quantity = 1},
                           }; and you want to search with the next criteria  var queryItems = new List<QueryItem>
                                 { new QueryItem {Caption = "Name", Value = "v*", Separator = NextItem.Last};

Comment: @Hohhi isMatch is a method of Regex.
In your original question you ask about regular expression checks.

Comment: how to do regex replace in this example.