# Dynamically constructing an Expression<Func<T,bool>> doesn't work for GreaterThen

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, expression

Hi I have a simple query in Entity Framework:

```
using (var db = new BookstoreContext())
{
    return db.Book
        .Where(w => w.PublishedYear > 2005)
        .ToList();
}
```

Now I want to change this query to something more dynamic. But I want to change, not only the constant value (`2005`) but also my column field (`PublishedYear`).

I am looking for several days how to dynamically build an `Expression<Func<,>>`. Now i found this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845059/how-do-i-dynamically-create-an-expressionfuncmyclass-bool-predicate) and I'm trying to do so. So far I came to this:

```
public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooksGreaterThan(string columnName, object value)
{
    using (var db = new BookstoreContext())
    {
        return  db.Book
            .Where(GreaterThan(columnName, value))
            .ToList();
    }
}

public Expression<Func<Book, bool>> GreaterThan(string columnName, object value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Book), "w");
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, columnName);
    var body = Expression.GreaterThan(property, Expression.Constant(value));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Book, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

But in line 15 (`var body = Expression.Greater...`) a exception is thrown:

> > The binary operator GreaterThan is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Int32'.

**PS**:
My column `PublishedYear` of the table `Book` is `INT NULL` or `int?` in entity framework class.

The expression `w => w.PublishedYear > 2005` so why it keep saying that don't exists this operation? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the nullability. You could probably get away with just adding a conversion expression from the value to the type of the property:

```
public Expression<Func<Book, bool>> GreaterThan(string columnName, object value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Book), "w");
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, columnName);
    var propertyType = typeof(Book).GetProperty(columnName).PropertyType;
    var body = Expression.GreaterThan(property,
         Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), propertyType));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Book, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

This is now effectively doing:

```
w => w.PublishedYear > (int?) 2005
```

... which is what the C# code is doing implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If the value `NULL` for `PublishedYear` is permitted but does not actually occur, perhaps you can change the type of argument `value` in both functions to `int?` and use `value.Value` for the comparison in `Expression.GreaterThan`.